# TypeScript или CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript

Какой язык стоит учить, по вашему мнению, с расчетом на написание HTML5 приложений, как нативных (WinRT), так и браузерных web-приложений. Больше склоняюсь к TypeScript - нравится статическая типизация и хорошая поддержка автодополнения IntelliSense, но волнует будущее этого языка, ввиду большего распространения его конкурента - CoffeeScript.

Comment: JavaScript знаю неплохо, но одного только знания этого языка недостаточно, к сожалению, для комфортного написания более-менее больших приложений, поэтому, вопрос не в выборе между JavaScript и других языков, а в выборе между TypeScript и CoffeeScript.

Comment: >JavaScript знаю неплохо, одного только знания этого языка недостаточно, к сожалению, для комфортного написания более-менее больших приложений

чего? что же вам такое большое было не комфортно писать?

тем более в ES 6 есть [всё тоже](https://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures)

Comment: ES6 - это будущее, но некоторые его фишки хотелось бы использовать сегодня.

Comment: Кофескрипт — попытка приделать человеческий синтаксис. Семантика как была так и остается обезображенной родовыми травмами. Фасад дома отремонтировали, но в бомж в подвале остался вонять.

Тайпскрипт — попытка зайти чисто со стороны семантики, не трогая базовый синтаксис. Выгнали бомжа из подвала, но как на фасаде была облезлая штукатурка так и осталась.

Вот такой прекрасный выбор.

Comment: @drdaeman, такое чувство, что мы разным яваскриптом пользовались

Comment: Если будете использовать продукты и технологии Microsoft, то первый лучше. Но как подсказали высше без JavaScript далеко не уйти.

Comment: @drdaeman - по поводу кофескрипта не согласен, на мой взгляд это попытка сделать из javascript'a что-то типа rubyscript :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope coffescript видать придумали для умственно отсталых и труъ-человеков из индустрии красоты и моды, которым вдруг стался не по душе синтаксис JS.

Comment: @lampa я о том-же :)

Comment: Кофе уходит, а типаскрипт имеет шансы жить долго, а то и вовсе переехать в браузер. Впрочем, я не уверен, взять тот же сервелат...

Answer (score 4):

учите javascript, это же база

Answer (score 0):

не уверен, что сейчас можно точно оценить перспективы каждого из них - оба появились недавно (TypeScript и вовсе практически вчера), и на их развитие может повлиять множество факторов. Но так или иначе, если вы вдруг собрались связать свою профессиональную деятельность с одним из них и зарабатывать программированием на нем  на кусок хлеба, то я бы советовал не забывать о том, что оба могут "не выстрелить" - мало ли было таких примеров. Хотя все же я бы склонялся в пользу TypeScript - скорее всего, Microsoft имеет на него какие-нибудь далекоидущие планы. Впрочем, это не более, чем мое скромное мнение

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript набирает популярность. К тому же, он совместим с ES6, т. е. корректная на ES6 программа корректна (возможно, помимо ошибок типа) для тайпскрипта.

А вот у CoffeeScript'а свой собственный синтаксис. Причём, насколько я представляю, местами достаточно странный.

Так что, рекомендую TypeScript. Ну и как уже написали, Javascropt по-любому надо выучить.